# Android MediaPlayer won't start playing audio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I have a very simple Android application where an audio file should start playing as soon as the app opens up.

But the audio doesn't play at all and I get this warning in Logcat: `MediaPlayer finalized without being released`

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

I initialized MediaPlayer with the MediaPlayer.create() method, so I shouldn't have to prepare or release the mPlayer.

I'm not sure if it's a problem in my code or just a sound output problem with the android emulator.

UPDATE:
I tried to declare the MediaPlayer outside of the onCreate() method and initialize it inside onCreate(). Now I don't get the warning but it still doesn't play the audio.

Updated MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I added 3 callbacks, onPreparedListener, onErrorListener, and onCompletionListener in my application.

Updated MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.e("Error", "onError: " + what);
                return false;
            }
        });

        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.i("Completion", "onCompletion: Completed");
            }
        });

        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.i("Prepared", "onPrepared: Prepared MediaPlayer");
            }
        });

        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

I get the prepared log pretty much as soon as the app starts, and I get the completed log after I wait out the duration of my audio file. I don't get any error logs in between.

Comment: Your `MediaPlayer` instance is local to `onCreate()`, so it'll be released almost immediately. Try making the instance a member of your `MainActivity` class.

Comment: I tried declaring it outside of the onCreate() method and initialize it inside onCreate(), now I don't get the warning but it still doesn't play the audio.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: It's updated now.

Comment: That worked for me with my own audio file. Make sure the file is valid and is in a supported format, and/or add [callbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#Callbacks) (e.g. an error listener) to find out more about what's going on.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the emulator audio playback? Have you ever experienced similar problems with the emulator's audio>

Comment: My experience is that the emulator can be unpredictable with respect to audio (and sometimes other things). But, try the other things I suggested (checking your audio file and adding callbacks) before you give up :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I added my callbacks and I updated the code. I do get both the logs from the onPreparedListener and the onCompletionListener, but the audio still doesn't play.

Comment: If the completion callback is being called at the expected time, that suggests the issue may be downstream somewhere. Here are some more things you could check. What format is the audio file? (Maybe you mentioned that and I missed it.) Does the audio file play correctly elsewhere? Do you have a device you can test on? Can you test on the emulator with different Android versions? Do any other methods of playing sound work on the emulator? Stupid question, but does your computer produce any sound at all? If you haven't solved it yet, I'd suggest gathering some more diagnostic info.

Comment: The audio file is mp3, and it plays fine in the music player on my computer. I don't have an android device available to me right now, but I was planning on testing it on a device later when I can get one. But if it plays fine on the real device later, then it must be a problem with the emulator, right?

Comment: A remaining question is whether the emulator plays any sound at all (e.g. if you can get it to play a notification sound or something). You could also check e.g. Logcat for errors while the app is running (although Logcat output can be difficult to sift through). You could also convert the file to another format and try that. Lastly, if the file is something you're free to share, you could have someone else try it to see if the problem is environment-dependent. But yes, it sounds like it could be an emulator issue (although I can't say that for sure).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I figured it out. When my wireless headphones ran out of battery I switched to wired headphones, and the audio played when I ran the app again. It seems like a problem with using Bluetooth on the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

The first you must declare the class of MediaPlayer,

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

I expect this code work and helpful to everyone that read this post

Comment: It might be more useful if you could post a complete example similar to Yixuan Li's, because there are issues at play here like object lifetime that aren't clear from an out-of-context snippet like that. Also, if you haven't already, you might try compiling and testing your code, as I think there may be some problems with it. (In any case, Yixuan Li's updated code works for me, so I think the issue probably lies elsewhere.)

Comment: Declare MediaPlayer class with global variable mediaPlayer, so on call again the variable mediaPlayer inside onCreate. this variable must inside onCreate mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song); mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();

Comment: I think that still may be wrong, and the player doesn't need to be global/static/etc., if it's handled properly. Anyway, you can edit your post and add a complete example. That'd make it easier for people to try it out themselves.

Comment: The snippet is wrong, `MediaPlayer.create` is a static function.